# c# FileInfo exists returning false for network path to file

Tags: c#, file

Trying the following..

```
bool success = File.Exists(@"\\comp01\BatchFiles\InputFile\Test.txt");
```

And its returning `false` (File does exist)

When I try

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\comp01\BatchFiles\InputFile");
if (dirInfo.Exists)
```

It returns `true`.

So it can find the path but not the file ?

Any reason why ?

Comment: The paths are different.

Comment: Your path should not be Diffrent please remark it.

Comment: sorry that was just a typo they are the same. Will edit now

Comment: Can it be access restriction, like you can read content of `BatchFiles`, but you do not have access to read it sub-folder content `InputFile` for some reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a FileInfo instance and check if that exists;

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"\\comp01\BatchFiles\InputFile\Test.txt");
var exists = fi.Exists;
```

Comment: Any reason why this should make a difference?

Comment: Using FileInfo still seems flaky. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Even if I can open the path in Windows Explorer, sometimes FileInfo.Exists still returns false.

Comment: I always call fi.Refresh() before checking exists. As it doesn't do live change feedback.